# Use table in order by case when does not work

Tags: sql, db2

I am running this query but I get an error

```
select *
from dog
order by case
             when exists(
                     select 1 from dogfood where dog.dogid = dogfood.dogid)
                 then '1'
             else '0' end;
```

So 2 tables, `dog` and `dogfood` which both have a `dogid` column. I get this error:

> [42703][-206] "DOG.DOGID" is not valid in the context where
> it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14
> [56098][-727] An error occurred during implicit system action type
> "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206",
> > SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "DOG.DOGID"..
> > SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.26.14

I just want to order the dog by if it has a row in `dogfood`. A solution would be querying the result in the select clause and refer to it in the order by clause, but I want it in the order by clause for my application. I am curious why this query isn't working, I double checked for syntax errors but I could not find any. Am I missing something obvious? I would expect I could refer to a table in the order by which I queried in the select/from clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=subselect-order-by-clause)

> sort-key-expression
> An expression that is not simply a column name or an unsigned integer constant. The query to which ordering is applied must be a
> subselect to use this form of sort-key. **The sort-key-expression cannot
> include a correlated scalar fullselect (SQLSTATE 42703)** or a function
> with an external action (SQLSTATE 42845).

But since it is not correlated you can use `IN` with a fullselect

```
select *
from dog
order by 
  case when dog.dogid in (select dogid from dogfood)
      then '1' else '0' end;
```